# where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'ConfigurationChange'

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

pretty sure that did work yesterday

```
ConfigurationChange
| where SvcPreviousState  == "Running"
| where SvcState == "Stopped"
| order by TimeGenerated
```

today I get in my Analytics Workspace

```
where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'ConfigurationChange'
```

As far I can see nothing as changed in the Analytics or VM configuration which should fill the results.

On Rsource Group Layer it works fine

Any idea why that is not in the listed query tables of the analytics workspace anymore ?

Answer (score 1):

If you query logs at the resource group level, the query will scan across ALL workspaces that contain any data for that resource group, and would effectively union all of the tables across all of the workspaces.  so if *any* workspace has that table, the query would succeed.

If you target a *specific* workspace, that table might not exist?  You'd need to verify that the workspace you're targeting does indeed have that table.

[From the docs for that table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/configurationchange), it appears that table belongs to change tracking solution, which maybe only has been turned on in specific subscriptions or areas?

in your *specific* case, you'd create a fake datatable that has ALL the columns you would reference in the query as the `MissingTable`:

```
let MissingTable = datatable(SvcPreviousState: string, SvcState: string, TimeGenerated: datetime) [];
union isfuzzy=true MissingTable,ConfigurationChange
| where SvcPreviousState  == "Running"
| where SvcState == "Stopped"
| order by TimeGenerated
```

and then do a fuzzy union using that fake table and the real one (for me, does not exist.  in workbooks in edit mode, you'll get a success with warning:

[image: success with warning]

if you stop editing and run the query, you'll just get the standard no results message (using any custom no rows message settings) :

[image: no results]

if the table exists and has rows, you'd get rows instead.

Comment: thanks for the explenation and the documentation Link. Can't see what to configure for the ConfigurationChange Table. Is there an easy way for that ?